# Deserialize List<T> with type from runtime

Tags: c#, json, .net

I am trying to deserialize a response from an API and the type is retrieved at runtime:

```
var modelType = Type.GetType($"Namespace.{itemname}").GetType();
```

Then I call a generic method passing the type in (with refrection). After the API call i try to deserialize it form the response:

```
var obj= await response.Content.ReadAs<List<T>>();
```

but it gives this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.RuntimeType' because the type requires a JSON string value to deserialize correctly.

I also tryied reading it as string and then using the JsonConvert

```
var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(str);
```

Also same error. Anybody got any idea how to do it? thanks!

Comment: What is `T` in your question? Where does it come from?

Comment: T is always a simple class (I'd like to use T because I have a lot of them)

Comment: Is modelType variable your T?

Comment: I _think_ that `Type.GetType($"Namespace.{itemname}").GetType();` is wrong: You resolve the type, and then you call "GetType" on an instance of type "RuntimeType", so you get something like the type of Type. You should probably double check that part or post a more complete example?

Comment: @A.Chiesa you are right! now is working! thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent! I'm going to add an answer with the specific problem, so we can close the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the line `var modelType = Type.GetType($"Namespace.{itemname}").GetType();`.

This code resolves a type by name (`Type.GetType($"Namespace.{itemname}")`) but then calls on this Type instance the method `GetType`. This gives you the type of the instance, which is, confusingly, `System.Type` or `System.RuntimeType`, depending upon the framework version.

Removing the extra `GetType()` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use generics with a runtime type.  That said, there are serialize/deserialize overloads that takes a type argument.

In your case, since you have a List where T is a runtime type, you'd need reflection to dynamically create your generic type at runtime and then pass it into the second argument:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>);
var modelType = Type.GetType($"Namespace.{itemname}");
var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, listType.MakeGenericType(modelType));
```